# How can I extract all digits from a C++ string of a very large number?

Tags: c++, string

I have a file of very large numbers that will not fit into the int data type. My task is to take each individual digit of the large number and assign it to its own node in a linked list. I also need to read 2 large numbers at a time in the file, with each number in the file separated by a newline.

So far I have this for testing purposes:

```
    inFile.open("file.txt");
    inFile >> bigNumber;
    for(const auto &c : bigNumber) {
         cout << c << endl;
    }
```

This prints the correct value, but the problem is it's a char and I cannot add or multiply this digit. How can I extract each individual digit from the string as an int?

I was also told that this is possible with a stringstream, though I don't know how these objects work at all? I'm very open to better/cleaner methods of doing the above task if possible.

Comment: You're implementing [arbitrary percision arithmatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). There's lots of source material on the topic.

Comment: I imagine there are far cleaner ways but cheap and cheerful is to acknowledge that a char is an unsigned short with the ASCII value of your char. Subtract 48 (ASCII value of 0) and you have your number. Cast as int to complete.

Comment: @BrianBeacom A `char` is *not* an `unsigned short`!

Comment: @aruisdante cheers for clarification, with explanation realise I'm being silly/oversimplifying

Comment: I know it's not strictly C++, but I'd think this was a fine time to use `atoi`.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: Oh the things we know that aren't so.  `char` is not the same type as `unsigned short`, although it could be the same size.  `char` may or may not be unsigned.  `char` is a minimum or 8 bits, but may be more (C++ defines a byte as `sizeof (char)` but it isn't always 8 bits), see the `CHAR_BIT` constant.  And the numeric value of a character might not be ASCII.

Comment: I'm curious what platform a ``byte`` isn't 8 ``bits``. You're right that a ``char`` is defined as being *exactly one byte* and only *at least 8 bits*

Comment: @aruisdante, `char` could either be signed or unsigned

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I realized I had said *unsigned* too late to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do:

To read the value as an ascii code, you can use

```
char c = 'a';
int i = (int) a; 
/* note that the int cast is not necessary -- int i = a would suffice */
```

To convert the character '0' -> 0, '1' -> 1, etc, you can write

```
char c = '4';
int i = a - '0';
/* check here if i is bounded by 0 and 9 */
```

Comment: Importantly, subtracting `'0'` works *even if the character set is not ASCII*

Comment: For the '0'-> 0 case, is this the "standard" way of converting? `a - '0'` doesn't seems more like a 'trick' than something that would be obvious to other programmers reading this code. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: `a - '0'` is obvious! I wouldn't worry about that.